# Evaluate $\frac{2021!+2020!}{2019!+2018!}.$

Tags: arithmetic, factorial

Evaluate $\displaystyle{\frac{2021!+2020!}{2019!+2018!}}.$

I think we can write this as $\displaystyle{\frac{2018!\cdot2019\cdot2020\cdot2021+2018!\cdot2019\cdot2020}{2018!\cdot2019+2018!}},$ but I don't know if this is the right direction.

Comment: Cancel 2018! from Numerator and Denominator.

Comment: So we get $\displaystyle{\frac{2019\cdot2020\cdot2021+2018!\cdot2019\cdot2020}{2019+2018!}}$ this right?

Comment: No. In the denominator, you have : $2018!(2019+1)=2018! \times 2020$.

Comment: Wait, so basically $2019!+2018!=2018!\times2020?$

Comment: Yes. You've got it right.

Comment: Wait, I'm not sure how $2019!+2018!=2018!\times2020,$ though.

Comment: $2019!+2018!=2019.2018! +2018!=(2019+1)2018!=2020.2018!$

Comment: @Frost Bite Do you know the distributive property $ab+ac=a(b+c)$?

Comment: yes, I do know it. @Koro I understand now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{2021!+2020!}{2019!+2018!}$$

$$ =\frac{2022\cdot2020!}{2020\cdot2018!}$$

$$= \frac{2022\cdot2020\cdot2019}{2020}$$

$$= 2022\cdot2019$$

Answer (score 1):

> Evaluate $\displaystyle{\frac{2021!+2020!}{2019!+2018!}}$.

$$=\displaystyle{\frac{2018!\cdot2019\cdot2020\cdot2021+2018!\cdot2019\cdot2020}{2018!\cdot2019+2018!}}=\displaystyle{\frac{2019\cdot2020\cdot2021+2019\cdot2020}{2019+1}}=2019\cdot2020\displaystyle{\left(\frac{2021+1}{2020}\right)}=2019\cdot 2022=4082418$$

Comment: I'm not fully sure how u went from the expanded version I started off with the your second step.

Comment: @FrostBite He divided by $2018!$ everywhere.